# Azure Active Directory integration with SAP HANA Cloud Platform

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-acs, sap-cloud-platform

I am Following document "Tutorial: Azure Active Directory integration with SAP HANA Cloud Platform" at location https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn948540.aspx, when I searched "SAP HANA cloud platform" in the list of applications in application gallery while adding new application into my active directory, it didn't found anything. How can I resolve this issue?

Regards,

Pranjal

Comment: It is very clearly stated that you have to have a SAP HANA account! Do you have such ?
The second explicit requirement is `You need to deploy your own application or subscribe to an application on your SAP HANA Cloud Platform account to test single sign on. `
Did you complete these two requirements before placing your question ?

Comment: Yes, I have a SAP HANA cloud platform account, and I have many applications deployed on that. The issue is in my windows azure portal where while adding a new application in my active directory when I perform search in application gallery it does not list out "SAP HANA cloud platform".

Comment: ok, I also do not see SAP Hana, it is reported. Cannot do anything more to help you!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for this feature made Online before the feature (SAP Hana integration) has been roll out to the customers. As of 2015-03-31, SAP Hana Cloud is available in the Applications Gallery of Azure Active Directory. You may now go test your integration!